# Magento Migration from 1.9.1 to 2.1.2 error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am using magento data migration tool. When i try to run this code

```
bin/magento migrate:data C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.1.0\config.xml
```

It returns an error

> [0;31m[2016-12-26 08:48:20][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_used_for_customer_segment

There were other errors and I used map.xml to ignore them but it is not working for this error. I added this code block in my map.xml

```
<ignore>
<field>customer_eav_attribute.is_used_for_customer_segment</field>
</ignore>
```

But the error is still there. How can I fix this error?

Comment: have you tried with reset? or new database? also make sure you have correct file names in config.xml

Comment: I started on a fresh magento 2 installation. I have linked the correct databases and map file. Do i need to add any other files in config.xml?

Comment: To get the solution for this error we are happy to help you:https://www.elsner.com/magento-2-migration-services/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the `map-eav.xml.dist` file to map fields in EAV tables. The main `map.xml.dist` file only handles mapping of non-EAV tables.

FYI, there are also a couple other sets of tables—for tier prices and customer visit logs—that have their own custom map files separate from `map.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting below error while migrating data from **magento 1 to magento 2**. Can someone help me regarding this?

> Error - php bin/magento migrate:settings
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.7.0.2/config.xml

[2019-01-21 08:56:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started [2019-01-21 08:56:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started [2019-01-21 08:56:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started [2019-01-21 08:56:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started [2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec

```
[UnexpectedValueException] Invalid parameter configuration provided for $sourceDocument argument of Migration\RecordTransformer 

migrate:settings [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--]
```